# Approximate inverse of large sparse matrix with small diagonal element

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-arrays, inverse

I need to find inverse of a large sparse matrix with small diagonal element. I follow this question - [Is there any way to obtain an approximate inverse for very large sparse matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/is-there-any-way-to-obtain-an-approximate-inverse-for-very-large-sparse-matrices) and try to use [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/is-there-any-way-to-obtain-an-approximate-inverse-for-very-large-sparse-matrices?answertab=oldest#tab-top)'s answer. But the problem is it is not converging for small diagonal element. For example

```
n = 40; (*Dimension of matrix*)
X = 10.; (*Diagonal element*)
s = SparseArray[{
    Band[{1, 1}] -> X,
    Band[{1, 2}, {20, 21}] -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    Band[{2, 1}, {21, 20}] -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    Band[{1, 8}, {14, 21}] -> 1,
    Band[{8, 1}, {21, 14}] -> 1
    }, {n, n}]

f = LinearSolve[s];
aInv = f[SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1.}, {n, n}, 0.]];

inv1 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1/Normal[Diagonal[s]], {n, n},0.];
sparseIden = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1., {n, n}, 0.];

niter = 5;(*number of iteration*)
Do[
  residual1 = inv1.s - sparseIden;
  delta1 = -residual1.inv1;
  inv1 = inv1 + delta1;
  Max[Abs[residual1]]//Print;
, {i, niter}]
```

gives an output

> $0.1 \\ 0.04 \\ 0.0034 \\ 0.00003332 \\ 4.11443 \times 10^{-9}$

which shows a fair convergence. But for smaller `X` it is not converging at all. I try to check it over a range of of `X` and it looks like it is converging only for `X>5`.

[image]

Since it is a small matrix I use `Inverse` which gives an exact inverse (`Max[Abs[residual1]]` ~ $10^{-16}$ for all `X`). But it is not an good option if `n->10000`.

What would be a suitable method to find inverse in such cases?

Comment: Of course, your "approximate inverse" may well be much denser than your original one.

Comment: @J.M., my main concern is the applicability of the method for small diagonal elements. I didn't find any method which can handle such large sparse matrices. Later I tried to get some selective elements ([How to find selected elements of inverse of a banded matrix without inverting it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104322/how-to-find-selected-elements-of-inverse-of-a-banded-matrix-without-inverting-it)) near diagonal, but that didn't go well either.